# распознавание капчи с помощью pytesseract

Tags: python, pil, cv2, pytesseract

У меня есть капча, которую мне надо научиться распознавать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала я ее видоизменяю, удаляя полоски и фон, получая вот такое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но pytesseract все равно не может распознать эту задекодированную капчу. Подскажите пожалуйста. Может мне нужно взять другой конфиг(я использую --oem 3 --psm 7) или разбить капчу на символы и перебрать каждый, а в конце собрать все воедино, и как это можно сделать.

Мой код:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from colorama import Fore
from PIL import Image


im = Image.open("img.jpg")

im2 = Image.new("RGB", im.size,255)


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
            

cfg = r'--oem 3 --psm 7'
verifcode = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('output.jpg'), config=cfg).replace(" ", "")
print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "\nКод верификации:", verifcode)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `https://cloudmersive.com/ocr-api` для меня это выдало наибольшую точность вот код который позволит туда, обратится:

```
import requests
import re


class CaptchaSolver:
    def __init__(self, proxy=None):
        self._s = requests.Session()
        if proxy:
            self._s.proxies.update({'http': proxy, 'https': proxy})
        self.__event_validation = None
        self.__view_state = None
        self.__save_data(self._s.get('https://cloudmersive.com/ocr-api').text)

    def __save_data(self, text):
        self.__event_validation = re.findall(r'__EVENTVALIDATION".*value="(.*)"', text)[0]
        self.__view_state = re.findall(r'__VIEWSTATE".*value="(.*)"', text)[0]

    @staticmethod
    def __get_captcha_result(text):
        result = re.findall(f'TextResult":.*"(.*)"', text)
        if result:
            return result[0].replace('\\n', '')
        return ''

    def solve(self, image: open) -> str:
        """
        Method for solving regular text captcha.
        :param image: open(file, 'rb')
        """
        data = {
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': self.__event_validation,
            '__VIEWSTATE': self.__view_state,
            'ctl00$MainContent$LanguageSelector': 'eng',
            'ctl00$MainContent$btnUpload2': 'Photos of Docs to Text'
        }

        r = self._s.post('https://cloudmersive.com/ocr-api', data=data,
                         files={'ctl00$MainContent$FileUploadBox': image})
        if not r.ok:
            return ''
        self.__save_data(r.text)
        return self.__get_captcha_result(r.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    captcha_solver = CaptchaSolver()
    print(captcha_solver.solve(open('img.png', 'rb')))
```

Этот ocr лучше работает на необработанных вами изображениях
На первом изображении выдаёт `922412` не распознало семёрку
На втором `15 90 02` если убрать пробелы то всё правильно.
Вы можете попробовать добавить размытие перед treshhold, чтобы убрать не чёткости и сделать текст чёрным (ocr показывают при этом большую точность)
`pytesseract` - несильно хорош в распознавание искажённых букв

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все работает, хоть и с небольшими промахами, но это уже намного лучше! Я тоже хотел просто подавать запрос на сайт через requests, но я смотрел именно сайты которые обходят капчу, а не для простого доставания текста с картинки, но отказался от этой идеи тк те сайты которые я смотрел были платные

Comment: cloudmersive.com штуковина со странностями, выбрал бесплатную подписку, делаю запрос в API а оно мне добавь карту иначе API нельзя пользоваться. Код выше вообще у меня не сработал, брал код с документации cloudmersive